# FRONT_CAMERA not supported d error: Video Chat Feature powered by Applozic

Tags: java, android, android-camera, applozic

I have the following issue (since about a week) and unfortunately I have not been able to resolve it:

**I'm using applozic especially as a video chat feature for my app**. I want to deploy it on an android 6.0 powered smart glasses devices. The app starts, connects to the applozic server, all functions from my app work well and then, when I try to connect a WebRTC video call, this is what happens:

```
 01-31 11:02:41.331 3580-3580/com.package.name W/System.err:
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: FRONT_CAMERA is not supported on
 this device [...]
```

Audio works, the chat feature works, so I "believe" the error message that is thrown. Is there anything I can do from my side to fix this issue, **or is applozic simply not supporting devices that only have one camera?**

I already tried the following:

1. Uninstalled and reinstalled the camera app
2. Installed a different android camera app
3. Added all additional manifest permissions I could think of
4. Logged into the web app (Java Script API) with the device and it works
5. Tested it with 5 different smart phones and it worked well, which made me 
   believe applozic does not support devices that only have 1 camera.
6. Compiled + Targeted a higher and a lower SDK

Answer (score 1):

After contacting applozic (they responded very fast what I appreciated), I was presented with a workaround approach by inserting a modified audioVideo module. After tweaking this module a little bit, I'm now able to use a device that either only has a front, or back camera when doing a live video call.

So I suggest that if you run into the same issue, you contact applozic support: https://www.applozic.com/ and refer to this stackoverflow thread.